# Is there any alternative to storing the DI container reference in Application variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an C# MVC application. I am using Unity Container to resolve my dependencies. For injecting dependencies inside MVC controller, I am using constructor injection. To achieve this I have replaced the MVC Controller Builder factory with my Controller Builder factory on Application_Start event i.e.

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{    
 IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

 //All container registrations ....

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new 
UnityControllerFactory(container)); 

//Store reference of container in application object
HttpContext.Current.Application["Injector"] = container;   
}
```

However I need instance of container to resolve dependencies at certain places where it is not possible to do constructor injection, for e.g. Application_AuthenticateRequest event. So as a fallback, I have stored a reference to the container in the Application object. I used this instance to resolve references.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var container = HttpContext.Current.Application["Injector"] as 
 IUnityContainer;
 var service = container.Resolve<IService>();
}
```

Is it ok to store the container reference in application variable or is there any other recommended practice ?
I also know there is Property Injection. Can I use it in this scenario?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, in particular, but it's usual for DI containers to have a way to access the container singleton. Look into the documentation for your container regarding how to get the container instance manually.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: This is actually not something that is "usual for DI containers" at all. The only library I recall that allowed this was StructureMap, but in later releases they deprecated the API that allowed having a static accessor to a single container instance.

Comment: Rather than storing it in the `HttpContext.Current.Application`, can you make it a property of the global application class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should strive to prevent access to the container from within application code. Within the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) however, it is typically okay to access the container directly, and it is often impossible to prevent this anyway. Your `Application_AuthenticateRequest` can be considered part of your Composition Root, so it is fine to access the container (and there is really no way around it).

You can however simplify the code to the following:

```
private static IUnityContainer container;

protected void Application_Start() 
{    
    container = new UnityContainer();

    ...
}

protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var service = container.Resolve<IService>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a [custom `UnityResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection), and in `Application_Start()`, we configure (via `GlobalConfiguration.Configure([...])`, but you could do otherwise I guess) the resolver this way :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{   
    UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    // This contains our actual container registrations.    
    UnityRegistrer.Register(container); 

    // IoC for WebAPI
    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

    // IoC for WebForms
    HttpContext.Current.Application.SetContainer(container);

    // IoC for MVC5
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

    // Configure other stuff like routes, tracing, error handling, authorization, etc.
}
```

I'm no expert in Web development at large, so maybe you want to tweak some stuff, but this has been working well for us.